# Where does the witch end up at the end of Seconds?

Tags: comics, time-travel

At the end of *Seconds*, Katie is trapped in a dead, empty world* with the witch. Katie says, "...you aren't alone. I'm here now. I'm in this world with you! ... we can still at least try to make it a little better." The witch is mollified, and Katie returns her to her home at Lucky's. But then Katie does just what she says she wouldn't do: she leaves.

* It might not be a totally dead world. It looks like there are some ice-giant-skeletons. But maybe they're dead too.

Katie wakes up in a world that seems pretty close to the one she started in. Where is the witch? Did Katie take her away from her source of mushrooms and then abandon her in a distant branch of probability space? Or does the bond between them mean that the witch got to go home too?

Does it matter that Lis used the final mushroom instead of Katie? Is Lis able to move people between branches of reality instead of just recklessly abandoning worlds? I recognize that Katie giving up the mushroom to Lis is an important part of her character arc, but I'm not sure how it fits in with the mechanics of the fictional world.